# Calling dir() in Python

Tags: python

What object is being queried when I call `dir()` in Python's interpreter?

I'm playing with a package that I want to be able to get the names for functions from the global dictionary. I thought that it would be `dir(__global)` but that wasn't it, nor was `dir(sys.modules)`.

If I type `dir()` into a fresh interpreter session it says

```
['__builtins__', '__doc__', '__name__', '__package__']
```

What would be the `ob` in `dir(ob)` that would give me this same response?

Comment: that was so much more than I needed to say, but any less and it thought my question was subjective. and as you can see, it is very very much so not.

Comment: It returns the current local scope if no args are passed to it. Your question could be better worded, as I'm still unsure what it is you are after.

Comment: how do i address the local scope? it is a python object correct? how do I address this object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`dir()` returns names in the current scope. I can't remember now if it's exactly equivalent to `locals().keys()`, or are there any differences.

Comment: and how can I address the current scope? what is that object?

Comment: @Narcolapser: The local scope is a dictionary behind the scenes, which `locals()` can return.

Comment: thats it! thank you. I'll mark you correct in 5 minutes when it lets me. xD

Comment: @eryksun: CPython implementation details are not proof of Python semantics. :P

Answer (score 0):

Re-reading your question 8 years later, I now wonder if you are asking about `dir()` run interactively at the Python prompt, a situation which I and the other answers entirely failed to address.

In that case the actual answer is:

When you type `dir()` in the Python interpreter, it runs `dir()` on the `__main__` module because that is the namespace in which the Python prompt runs the statements that you type.

To perform this operation yourself, simply run:

```
import sys
dir(sys.modules['__main__'])
```

You will see exactly the same names listed as when you run `dir()` interactively. Try making an assignment like `a = 1` then run both plain `dir()` and also the expression shown above; you will see that they both show the same list of names that now includes `'a'`.

---

The `dir()` method invokes complex and deep operations to try to predict which attributes might exist on the object you query — but runs under the handicap that it cannot actually try to access the attribute names it finds to see if they would return `AttributeError` or not. I know, this answer is way more detail than you want right now; but for those who might stumble on this question later with more complicated needs, "[Implementing `__dir__` (and finding bugs in Pythons)](http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/weblog/arch_d7_2011_05_21.shtml?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed:+voidspace+(The+Voidspace+Techie+Blog)#e1212)" is a blog post by Michael Food detailing some of the magic.