# How to reference other scopes from dir()

Tags: python, introspection

I want to know what is available in other scopes, or how many instances of certain class are running, etc.. that kind of things.

To make it sweet and short

```
print dir()
def func():
    #print dir(magic_keyword)
    print dir()
func()
```

What would be the "magic_keyword" to use to get the same results from within the function and from outside it?

I was checking [calling dir() in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8109066/calling-dir-in-python) but the question was never really answered.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are looking for the [`locals()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#locals) and [`globals()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#globals) functions.

`dir()`, without an argument, returns the equivalent of `locals().keys()`.

`globals()` is essentially the same as `locals()` at module scope, but in a function it returns the module scope variables.

```
>>> dir()
['__builtins__', '__doc__', '__name__', '__package__']
>>> locals().keys()
['__builtins__', '__name__', '__doc__', '__package__']
>>> def foo():
...     return locals().keys(), globals().keys()
... 
>>> foo()
([], ['__builtins__', '__name__', 'foo', '__doc__', '__package__'])
```